# What is the name for The husband to the Lady President or head of state

Tags: word-request

If the head of state or president is a lady , what do we call the husband to the Lady president . I know that when the man is the president , the wife is called the "First Lady" , what about the vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a special word that describes a *male* *First Lady!* But let me put some light on the title in concern.

The First Lady is **[not necessarily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Lady_of_the_United_States)** used for the wives of the presidents. The term is used for the White House's official hostess which is *generally* the wife of the president. Imagine if the president is a widow and the duties are performed by someone else (maybe daughters). In such case, they'll be the *First Lady*.

I think even if you have some female as the President, the constitution still requires some host/hostess at the White House. In such case, if her husband is not interested, again her daughter or some female would be appointed.

[Interesting paragraph on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_lady) (and the answer to this question):

> Should a woman be elected to the US Presidency, her spouse would ***presumably*** be known as ***"The First Gentleman"***. Such usage was made in various literary works describing the term of *a fictional woman President,* such as The Coming of the Quantum Cats.
>
> In [The Coming of the Quantum Cats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Coming_of_the_Quantum_Cats), in one universe, Nancy Reagan is the President of the United States and her mostly-disregarded husband Ronald is known as ***"The First Gentleman."***

Till date, there has been no [lady president](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States) and probably that's the reason, no title is thought yet! ;)

Comment: We also call our president's spouse "First Lady" this is in Kenya. We too have lady presidents in other parts of the world e.g Liberia , Brazil and what have you. I am not Necessarily referring to the U.S.A @ Maulik V

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is an unofficial title used for the wife of a head of state. But broadly, the term refers to the US President's wife.